# Rotating UILabels depending on page in UIScrollView like in Google+ App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, google-plus, titlebar

I have an application with several (8) different Views in a UIScrollView. They are circling so that you get to the first when you try to get "behind" the last and vice versa.
My problem is how to create a titlebar like in the Stream of the Google+ App. There the titles are circling with the pages and show the current visible page.
How could I realize that? Would it be possible to create a general class to use such a view in many different apps?

I've already tried to solve this problem with some different approaches, but they all didn't work (well). I can display labels above my scrollView and move them, but how far and with which text seems to be difficult for me.

So now I'm looking forward to your answers ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using two `UIScrollView`, one for the content and one for the headers. The header `UIScrollView` would be controlled by your view controller that is also a delegate of the main `UIScrollView`. Update the header `UIScrollView` whenever you receive a `-scrollViewDidScroll:` message from the main `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add label in customview and then add customviews in scrollView, you will get events for individual view, so you can rotate that view according to angle and keep label at fix place...